# Recorrer un documento XML con SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

Buenas!! estoy intentando recorrer los datos de un documento xml, por el momento bien, pero cuando tengo que tratar con los atributos de algunas etiquetas es cuando me pierdo.

```
$agenda = new SimpleXMLElement("prueba.xml", 0, true);
foreach($agenda->personas->persona as $persona) {
    echo $persona->nombre . "<br>";
    echo $persona->apellidos . "<br>";
    echo $persona->fechanac . "<br>";
    echo $persona->ciudad . "<br>";
    foreach($persona->contacto["tipo"] as $contacto) {
        switch($contacto){
            case "email":
                echo "<b>Email: " . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
            case "tlf":
                echo "<b>Teléfono: " . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Esto muestra todos los datos correctamente pero pasa olímpicamente de las etiquetas que tienen el atributo tipo

Answer (score 1):

Me autorespondo al haberlo solucionado, lo comparto por si alguno más tiene la misma duda.

El error estaba en el foreach que recorre los atributos.

```
foreach($persona->contacto as $contacto) {
        switch($contacto["tipo"]){
            case "email":
                echo "<b>Email: </b>" . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
            case "tlf":
                echo "<b>Teléfono: </b>" . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Con esa forma mostramos un código u otro dependiendo del tipo de valor de ese atributo.

Queda así el código final

```
$agenda = new SimpleXMLElement("prueba.xml", 0, true);

foreach($agenda->personas->persona as $persona) {
    echo $persona->nombre . "<br>";
    echo $persona->apellidos . "<br>";
    echo $persona->fechanac . "<br>";
    echo $persona->ciudad . "<br>";

    foreach($persona->contacto as $contacto) {
        switch($contacto["tipo"]){
            case "email":
                echo "<b>Email: </b>" . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
            case "tlf":
                echo "<b>Teléfono: </b>" . $contacto . "<br>";
                break;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```